# GNU screen starts a new session with root, but not with a normal user

Tags: debian, gnu-screen

So, my problem is simply that I can't get `screen` started on my user account. When I invoke it as superuser it works, under any circumstance, like a charm, but until now (that is, in the about last THREE and more hours of troubleshooting) there wasn't a single instance in which it would spawn a new session.

To give some context, this morning I installed Debian 9.0 (stretch) on a 64-bit processor. In the previous installation (Debian ~8.0) screen worked without flaws.

Here is a non-exhaustive list of my attempts at solving this issue:

1. I unmounted the partition mounted at my home directory, and logged in with my user account in a new environment where there wasn't trace of my old custom config files;
2. I tinkered with the `$TERM`-like variables, and also tried using `tset`;
3. I tried installing an older version of screen (`4.2.1-3+deb8u1`);
4. I made an attempt at running `apt-get purge screen` and then installing again the distribution-provided package.

None of these attempts (and even *others*) had an impact on how screen behaves. All of the times I did `screen; echo $?` (`$?` being a status-code variable, IIRC) I got `0` printed on my console.

I am resorting to this Q&A as a last and desperate solution :'-).

Comment: **Hint**: *perhaps* the problem lies in the system configuration of my user. I also did some research on this but nothing that I examined seemed suspicious. And if it interests you, `$TERM` is always equal to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: Please provide at least the error message you're getting or state that you don't even get an error message. Otherwise you likely won't get any helpful answers.

Comment: @AxelBeckert I don't get any, as implicitly stated before. This is what I see when typing `screen` on console, with my normal account:
`none@vacuum:~$ screen\n
none@vacuum:~$ echo $?\n
0\n
`. (Edit: comments don't allow newlines; added "\n"s to give an idea.)

Comment: Thanks. Stating things implicitly is probably not the best idea here. At least I don't see where that would have been. I think the best is to [continue the debugging on the screen-devel mailinglist](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-devel/2017-07/msg00032.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Amadeusz Sławiński pointed out on the screen-devel mailing list](https://superuser.com/q/1223015/539790) and [I confirmed in the according Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=869551#15), this is caused by your user name `none` which seems treated special by GNU Screen.